# Cancan Accessible By Not Displaying All Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Is there no-one out there who can assist with this?

Having problems finding records using cancan in my rails 3.2 app.

In my 'nas' index, I'm trying to display a list of 'nas' that belong to the current_user's locations.

The issue seems to be that there's no formal relationship between the user and the nas - the location owns the nas and the user owns the location.

Using the accessible_by method in my nas controller gives me unusual results. If I use the following in my ability.rb, I get an error :

```
 can :read, Nas, :locationusers => { :user_id => user.id }

 Error: undefined method `class_name' for nil:NilClass
```

And, if I change to:

```
 can :read, Nas, :locations => { :user_id => user.id }
```

I only get the nas listed for the users first location.

For example, if my user has locations with ids = 1,2,3 only the nas from location 1 are displayed.

Is there a way to display all the nas for the current user's locations using cancan or do I have to go about this differently?

My relationships are as follows:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :locationusers
   has_many :locations, :through => :locationusers
   ...
 end


class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :locationusers
  has_many :users, :through => :locationusers

  has_many :nas
  ...
end   

class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :location
end
```

In my ability.rb:

```
...
if user.role? :customer_admins
can :read, Nas, :locations => { :user_id => user.id }
..
```

NasController

```
 @nas = Nas.accessible_by(current_ability).all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cancan, the User is king. If you cannot draw a line from User to the Model you are trying to  authorize, it is not going to work. The easy solution is to model the relationship between `Nas` (the model in your example is called `Node`?) and `User`. This can be done via `Locationuser` (which is not shown in your example) as a has_many :through using the existing belongs_to.

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :locationusers, :through => :location
end
```

Now in your Cancan ability.rb, you can use:

```
can :read, Node, :locationusers => { :user_id => user.id }
```

(I changed `Nas` from your example to `Node` to correctly match the model)

Comment: Ok, at least I'm not crazy. Let me check that out now. S

Comment: Can't believe I've been stuck on that for so long. Sorted. 50 points :) Thanks. S

Comment: PS >> Cant award that bounty for 2 hours. Will do when I can.